# drop down navigation bar behind carousel

Tags: html, css

Trouble with navigation bar behind carousel. I understand an aware that this is a duplicate, I just can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I tired using z-index: 1000 no luck. I added the html and css file for the above the question. What more do you wantttt frooom meeee.

```css
/* Global */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Unordered list*/

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


/* Header **/

header {
  opacity: .8;
  background-color: #000;
  max-height: 55px;
}


/* list items */

header li {
  float: left;
  color: blue;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-items ul li ul li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-items ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  visibility: visible;
}

.nav-items a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}

header a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

header ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

header ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

header #branding h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff
}

header .highlight {
  color: #99c2ff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header .action-items {
  float: right;
}


/* Carousel css file */

.carousel-inner img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="container">

    <div id="branding">
      <h2><span class="highlight">Connect</span>Us</h2>
    </div>

    <nav class="nav-items">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Private Services</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a> Service 1 </a></li>
            <li><a> Service 2 </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Assesment</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav class="action-items">
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>

This is the html file above
```

Comment: provide the code or a link to the working example, otherwise is completely impossible to guess the problem, let alone the answer.

Comment: remember z-index only works on positioned elements, so your drop-down and your carousel should have position:relative. And many, many things like floats, opacity, transform, filter, etc create new stacking contexts.. so better get a good read about it.   -- Seriously, can't actually help if you don't show ANY of your code

Comment: @FacundoCorradini Yeah my bad, forgot to provide the code. I uploaded it now.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm trying to add the css file, but it keeps telling me I don't have enough words.

Comment: Ok I added the css file. @FacundoCorradini

Comment: The z-index appears fine. Your dropdown menu is a layer above your navigation links. What is your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working for you. The problem was that you had "Private services", "Service 1" and "Service 2" all in the same nav. The entire nav was set to z-index:1000 which means "Service" as well as the drop down options of "Service 1 and 2" were both in the same z-index.

This code sets the "Service 1 and Service 2" to a higher layer than "Private services". The dropdown options are now viewable.

```
  .dd {
position: absolute;
  z-index: 100111;
  visibility: visible;
  }
```

-

```
 <nav class="nav-items">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Private Services</a><dropdown class="dd">
          <ul>
            <li><a> Service 1 </a></li>
            <li><a> Service 2 </a></li>
            </ul></dropdown>
```

Full code:

```html
<style>/* Global */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Unordered list*/

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


/* Header **/

header {
  opacity: .8;
  background-color: #000;
  max-height: 55px;
}


/* list items */

header li {
  float: left;
  color: blue;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-items ul li ul li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-items ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  visibility: visible;
}
  .dd {
position: absolute;
  z-index: 100111;
  visibility: visible;
  }
  
.nav-items a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}

header a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

header ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

header ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

header #branding h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff
}

header .highlight {
  color: #99c2ff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header .action-items {
  float: right;
}


/* Carousel css file */

.carousel-inner img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}</style>
<header>

  <div class="container">

    <div id="branding">
      <h2><span class="highlight">Connect</span>Us</h2>
    </div>

  <nav class="nav-items">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Private Services</a><dropdown class="dd">
          <ul>
            <li><a> Service 1 </a></li>
            <li><a> Service 2 </a></li>
            </ul></dropdown>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Assesment</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav class="action-items">
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```